# Edit text not allowing keyboard input on device?

Tags: android, text, input, android-edittext

I have some text views and edit texts in a linear layout and for some reason when i run on the emulator input into the edit texts works fine but not on device. When i type into the edit text the text doesn't appear in the edit text box. Here's the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"  >

<TextView 
    android:text="Complete Order Form"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:gravity="center"/>

<TextView 
    android:text="Enter Name: "
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".25"/>

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/nameEdit"
    android:hint="Name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:text="Enter Address:"
    android:textSize ="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/addressEdit"
    android:hint="Address"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:text="Enter Phone: "
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/phoneNoEdit"
    android:hint="Phone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView 
    android:text="Enter Order Comments: "
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/comments"
    android:hint="Comments"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
   android:id="@+id/sendOrder"
    android:text="Continue to Payment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/dontSend"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Cancel" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit blunt so my answer will also be blunt. If you are talking about text not appearing in the box when you type with the emulator keyboard, then it is the emulator. To fix this, edit the emulator and enable hardware.

Also: Do you have a corresponding Java class which has an ActionListener for each element (including the EditText)? From there, you can use methods such as `getText()`.

I will edit this as necessary.

Comment: Sort of. When I run it on the emulator it works fine so I know the emulator is not the problem. Text doesn't appear in the box when I run the activity on an actual device. I've tried changing the input method on the device

Comment: Text doesn't appear in the EditText box? What I mean is the text in a text field that carries a string such as "Password". Is it that which doesn't show up?

Comment: I got it to work, I had switched the id's of a textview and an edit text by mistake. Thanks anyway